# CSS Grid nested inline-grid issue

Tags: css, css-grid

I have some css grid code where I have nest divs.
Here is the full code:

```css
#outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  border: 10px solid purple;
}

#outer-grid>div {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding: 10px;
}

#inner-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

#inner-grid>div {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-grid">
  <div id="inner-grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="inner-grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I have a wrapper div that uses css grid and 2 inline divs that uses inline-grid but for some reason is not side by side.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `#outer-grid>div` - what are the styles, applied under this selector, for?

Comment: No particular reason. Any part that's not for structure, just ignore

Comment: remove this line: `grid-column: 1 / -1;` and see if you get the desired layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` and `grid-column: 1 / -1;`.

```css
#outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  border: 10px solid purple;
}

#outer-grid>div {
  /* grid-column: 1 / -1; */
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding: 10px;
}

#inner-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

#inner-grid>div {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-grid">
  <div id="inner-grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="inner-grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can I only add 2 inner-grid's before it wraps? Can I add more and have them resize and not wrap?

Comment: @Tomazbyden2000  In your question, you did not write you may want more than two inner grids. My answer is referred to your code. Take a look here, it could be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid

Comment: @Tomazbyden2000 that's because you have defined the outer grid to have 2 columns.